# How to change Compatibility Level in SQL Azure, my command does not work

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to run:

```
ALTER DATABASE QA-10
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
GO
```

on a V12 SQL Azure DB, and I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

What am I doing wrong please?

I am doing this to downgrade the level from 120 to 110, to check if the 120 level is not causing issues with my Level 100 queries. The Query Optimiser was changed in V12 apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try to enclose the database name with brackets and see if the issue persist? Run the following query instead:

```
ALTER DATABASE [QA-10]
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
GO
```